# Can i export all azure active directory users to a MySQL database via a Runbook in azure automation?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

Can i export all azure active directory users to a MySQL database via a runbook in azure automation?
Someone who has some kind of code with for example firstname and lastname only of a user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Your code would look something like this.

```powershell
######## Connect to Azure AD ##################
# Get Azure Run As Connection Name
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
# Get the Service Principal connection details for the Connection name
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

# Logging in to Azure AD with Service Principal
"Logging in to Azure AD..."
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

######## Create CSV of all users ##################

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true
$userList = @()

foreach ($user in $users){
    $userex = $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty
    $userProperties = [ordered] @{
        accountEnabled=$user.GivenName
        userPrincipalName=$user.Surname

    }
    $u = new-object PSObject -Property $userProperties
    $userList += $u
}
$userList | Export-Csv  .\users.csv -NoTypeInformation

$csvFullPath = Resolve-Path .\users.csv

######## Import CSV data into MySql ##################

[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$mysqlConn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$mysqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=loadfiletest;UID=root;PWD=pwd"
$mysqlConn.Open()
$MysqlQuery = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$MysqlQuery.Connection = $mysqlConn
$MysqlQuery.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvFullPath' INTO TABLE loadfiletest.testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (GivenName, Surname)"
$MysqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Hi Merill, thanks for this answer, but can you also store it direct into the database instead of first to CSV?

Comment: You can construct a string that has all the insert commands and then use it in the CommandText. This way you can do it all in memory without writing to a local file.